# Django Database Access Optimization

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have few question running in my head for this given piece of code given below:

```
    architects_list=[8757,8755,7066,8736,6961,6955,4830,6949,208,4876,59,115]
    clauses = ' '.join(['WHEN id=%s THEN %s' % (pk, i) for i, pk in enumerate(architects_list)])
    ordering = 'CASE %s END' % clauses
    architects = User.objects.filter(pk__in=architects_list).extra(select={'ordering': ordering}, order_by=('ordering',))
    other_architects= User.objects.filter(Iam='Architect').exclude(pk__in=architects_list).annotate(pd =Count('projectdetail')).order_by('-pd')
    archs_all = architects|other_architects
```

1. When I concatenate the architects and other_architects using '|', i get an error "Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous" error at `archs_all = architects|other_architects`. When I use `list(itertools.chain(architects,other_architects))` everything goes fine. I don't want the second method as I suspect it bloats memory.
2. Does passing a queryset with say a million object to a paginator is memory inefficient, if yes what's the alternative?

Traceback:

```
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/harshai3/django/zingyhomes_lateral/apps/project/views.py" in get
  1251.         arch_objs = archs.page(1)
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in page
  50.         number = self.validate_number(number)
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in validate_number
  39.         if number > self.num_pages:
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in _get_num_pages
  86.             if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page:
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in _get_count
  72.                 self._count = self.object_list.count()
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in count
  291.         return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_count
  390.         number = obj.get_aggregation(using=using)[None]
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_aggregation
  356.         result = query.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(SINGLE)
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  781.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py" in execute
  174.         return self._record(self.cursor.execute, sql, params)
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py" in _record
  104.             return method(sql, params)
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  124.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  201.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/home/harshai3/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.     raise errorclass, errorvalue

Exception Type: OperationalError at /find-architects/
Exception Value: (1052, "Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous")
```

Comment: @Sahilkalra You're wrong that two queries will be made when combining the querysets - this is a common misconception. The query will be combined into a single statement, but the execution of the query will be delayed until the queryset is evaluated. Also, `chain()` will evaluate the queryset, not using the `qs.iterator()` function, so the full queryset results will be cached in memory.

Comment: nash, can you post the full traceback? And preferably, also the result of `str(archs_all.query)`. As for 2), no, this is not memory inefficient, as it will use a `LIMIT 10` (and optionally `OFFSET N`) SQL statement, and thus only receive 10 results from the database.

Comment: @knbk here is the trace http://pastebin.com/5N24k8Ky

Comment: @knbk..... Thanks.. taking back my comments

Comment: @knbk so should i use itertools.chain or try to concatenate those two queryset to one ?

Comment: If able, you should use a combined queryset (`qs1 | qs2`), as it will execute a single database query. What happens if you remove the annotation or apply it to `archs_all` instead?

Comment: @knbk removing annotations succeds in combining the querysets.. but i cant do it this way i have to order it by count of projects an architect have done :(

Comment: Can you apply the annotation and ordering to `archs_all` instead of `other_architects`? I suspect that combining an annotated and an unannotated queryset results in a name clash that causes the ambiguity described in the error.

Comment: it still results in same ambiguity error

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem. What Django version are you using? Can you post the user and project detail models, and the result of `str(archs_all.query)`?

Comment: @knbk take a look again at the code previously i had simplified a bit

Comment: "Does passing a queryset with say a million object to a paginator is memory inefficient" ...no it shouldn't be. The query is not yet executed, the paginator will page the query using `LIMIT`, also querysets have an iterator interface so they do not retrieve all million rows and store in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `id` in your `clauses` causes the ambiguity, as both the user table and the project detail table have an `id` field.

You can avoid this ambiguity by explicitly defining the table name:

```
clauses = ' '.join(['WHEN %s.id=%s THEN %s' % (User._meta.db_table, pk, i) for i, pk in enumerate(architects_list)])
```

However, I don't think this will solve all of your problems. Querysets with annotations can generally not be combined, I think the annotations of the second queryset are always lost (though I'm not 100% sure how it works). The combined ordering of two differently ordered querysets cannot be combined as-is.

Your query can be combined into a single query, if you specify a default for the SQL `CASE`:

```
from django.db.models import Q

architects_list=[8757,8755,7066,8736,6961,6955,4830,6949,208,4876,59,115]
clauses = ' '.join(['WHEN id=%s THEN %s' % (pk, i) for i, pk in enumerate(architects_list)])
clauses += ' ELSE 0' # or 999, depending on if you want the `other_architects` first or last
ordering = 'CASE %s END' % clauses
architects = (User.objects.filter(Q(id__in=architects_list) | Q(Iam='Architect'))
              .extra(select={'ordering': ordering})
              .annotate(pd=Count('projectdetail'))
              .order_by('ordering', '-pd'))
```